# Display validation errors on modal through ajax request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, bootstrap-modal

My jQuery script:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    // Handle modal shown event to focus on the first input
    $('#create_category, #edit_category').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('input:first').focus();
    });

    // Handle form submission
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Serialize the form data
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        // Make an AJAX request to your Laravel controller
        $.ajax({`your text`
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            success: function (response) {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // alert('Form not submitted')
                handleValidationErrors(error.responseJSON.errors);
            }
        });
    });

    // Function to handle validation errors and update the modal
    function handleValidationErrors(errors) {
        // Make an AJAX request to fetch validation errors
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/accounts/get-category-validation-errors',
            data: {
                category_code: $('.categoryCodeError').val(),
                category: $('.categoryError').val(),
                is_active: $('.isActiveError').val(),
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' // Include CSRF token
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.errors) {
                    alert('response error');
                } else {
                    // Continue with success scenario
                    alert('response success');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('error in error');
                //Update the modal with validation errors
                if (errors.category_code) {
                    $('.categoryCodeError').text(errors.category_code[0]);
                } else {
                    $('.categoryCodeError').text('444');
                }

                if (errors.category) {
                    $('.categoryError').text(errors.category[0]);
                } else {
                    $('.categoryError').text('444');
                }

                if (errors.is_active) {
                    $('.isActiveError').text(errors.is_active[0]);
                } else {
                    $('.isActiveError').text('444');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

My Json Response from url: '/accounts/get-category-validation-errors':
422 (Unprocessable Content)

```
{"errors": {"category_code": ["The category code field is required."],"category": ["The category field is required."],"is_active": ["The is active field is required."]}}
```

My blade view:

```
@if($errors->has('category_code'))
{{ $errors->first('category_code') }}
@endif

@if($errors->has('category'))
{{ $errors->first('category') }}
@endif

@if($errors->has('is_active'))
{{ $errors->first('is_active') }}
@endif
```

I've not been able to update anything so far to my modal if there is any error stopping the form from submitting.
On attempting to submit form with blank fields, I get the alert(error in error) because of failed validation. But the text spans are not updated with error messages.

Please guide.

I tried the validate method earlier but despite reordering my scripts in the main layout, the console says validate method is not defined.

Comment: `error:` means the *request* mechanism had an error, eg 404.   If your service returns a response, then it will be `success:` as the request itself was a success even if the actions within that success were not correct.  eg a 404 won't provide you with a an error based on category, nor will a 422.